# stuck in a login loop after updating drivers

Tags: drivers, login

Alright so I updated my amd drivers to the latest catalyst version, after almost two hours of trouble updating the drivers I somehow managed to complete the catalyst installing.

I rebooted my machine, and something has changed, I no longer had a GUI and a command line shell has appeared, now I entered the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

rebooted, this seemed to solve the problem yet of course a new one has started, I am now stuck in a login loop, whenever I login, it starts loading the desktop page and then immediately sends me back to the login screen, this goes on and on and on unless I enter a false password, in that case it just says:

```
Incorrect password
```

I already tried playing with the Xauthority and reinstalling the xorg Ubuntu desktop, yet no luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: And how could that be fixed

Comment: Have you tried solution mentioned in answer there?

Comment: "playing with the Xauthority"? What did you really do?

Comment: @Jajack, I tried most of the solutions suggested in there, none seem to work

Comment: @gubert, chowning the Xauthority

Answer (score 0):

I installed a AMD - fglrx driver package once and ended up in the same state. Here's what I did:

1. In the login screen <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to get into a tty
2. enter username and password
3. did sudo apt-get remove fglrx-core
4. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to login screen, reboot, it should be fixed.